# Regular expression that accepts only characters with accents

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that accepts only characters having accents. For the moment I'm using this one:

```
[ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöœøùúûüýþÿ]*$
```

Is there another expression, which is clearer than my expression?

Comment: That one actually looks pretty good.

Comment: A possible solution could be to use codes for those characters ...

Comment: You should include the `^` anchor at the start (so that you're not just matching end-of-string) and use a `+` instead of `*` unless you want to match an empty string.

Comment: [...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390618/regular-expression-that-accepts-only-characters-with-accents#comment41438558_26390618) or get rid of the `$` anchor, if you want to match accented characters within a larger string.  But definitely change the `*` to `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will solve your problem :

```
[œÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex isn't always the clearest way to handle text, even if it is the fastest.

You could assign your regular expression to a variable, then insert it via text interpolation:

```
accent_chars = '[ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöœøùúûüýþÿ]'

my_regex = '^...%s*...$' % accent_chars
```

You can also use these ranges:

```
[œÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]
```

Demonstration using Python 3:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöœøùúûüýþÿ'
>>> ''.join(re.findall('[œÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]', s))
'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöœøùúûüýþÿ'
>>> len(''.join(re.findall('[œÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]', s))) == len(s)
True
```

The downside is that it is not immediately clear to someone unfamiliar with Unicode that this covers every desired case.

Answer (score 1):

Since all characters except the `œ` are between characters 192 `À` and 255 `ÿ`, could you do something like looking ahead and checking they don't contain any of the characters in the range that you don't want? I'm not sure it improves anything compared to yours but **it's a bit shorter** and maybe, just maybe, clearer.

```
(?![÷×])[À-ÿœ]
```

Comment: I feel like that regex would need to include your paragraph explanation in the comments in order for it to be maintainable in the future.

Comment: The lookahead meant to be `(?![÷×])` ? Or what about `[œÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]` plus for the idea :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I wrote that on the phone (this too) thanks!

Comment: Nah, I think this is a headache to maintain. The maintainer would have to look up the Unicode table to check what is matched by the range. OP's solution is a bit long, but easier to see what is matched by the character class.

Comment: To be fair, that's why I noted that it's shorter an maybe just maybe clearer. To me it's pretty clear right now because I've been working on that area of the characters table and would recognize the expression, read it two months from now and wouldn't really know unless commented. But then again, I like to comment my code, so there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the [POSIX bracket expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) [:alpha:].

Then just prune the alphabetic characters from your string.

Comment: Some regex implementations support [character class subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) which means that the following might work depending on OP's specific situation: `[[:alpha:]-[a-zA-Z]]`

Comment: This may match more than what OP wants in Unicode mode, and doesn't match any character OP needs in ASCII mode. And depending on the language/library/mode, the regex may match character based on locale and the behavior may be totally different. It is not a good idea to use POSIX character class if you want to match a certain subset of character from it.